# Many-To-Many table or one table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I hava a doubt about of which of the two approach will be more performable,

let's presume i have a database for each user, each user could have many shops so i have a table `CONFIG` with columns like `SHOP_CONFIG` (id of the shop) and `POS_CONFIG` (id of the pos) *a shop could have more than one POS*.

Then i have the table with `ITEMS` that belong to the shops which has columns like `ID_ITEMS` `DESC_ITEMS`,
the items could be all the same for each `POS` in one `SHOP` or each `POS` could have different `ITEMS`. So now i have to see all the items for each `SHOP` / `POS`

So my doubt was:

Should i add an `ID` to `CONFIG` and then make a 3rd table like `SHOP_ITEMS` with `ID` of the `CONFIG` as foreign key and `ID_ITEMS` as foreign key?

Or could i just add columns `SHOP` and `POS` to `ITEMS` table?

(the table `CONFIG` is used anyway for other purpose)

Comment: this is quite confusing. generally you add a intersect table with both ids in it so that you can combine  any thing to every thing. such an intersect table is not needed when there i a 1:n Relation.

Comment: @nbk actually the relation between CONFIG (let's say we can call config table as shops table) is N:N with ITEMS.. or am i wrong?

Comment: @nbk i mean i'm quite sure that CONFIG and ITEMS is N:N but my colleague is convinced that we shouldn't use the intersect table..

Comment: I can't see hwta you wnat, make a EER diagram and show there what you mean. My commnt shows that a many to many relationship should be made in a relationship table. nad you don't need to add a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit longer example, but you can adjust it to your project.

---

```
-- Shop owner (user) OWN exists.
--
owner {OWN}
   PK {OWN}
```

```
-- Owner OWN owns shop number SHP# (of that owner).
--
shop {OWN, SHP#}
  PK {OWN, SHP#}

FK {OWN} REFERENCES owner {OWN}
```

```
-- Point of sale number POS#,
-- of shop number SHP#, of owner OWN exists.
--
point_of_sale {OWN, SHP#, POS#}
           PK {OWN, SHP#, POS#}

FK {OWN, SHP#} REFERENCES shop {OWN, SHP#}
```

```
-- Item ITM exists.
--
item {ITM}
  PK {ITM}
```

```
-- Item ITM is available in shop
-- number SHP#, of owner OWN.
--
item_shop {ITM, OWN, SHP#}
       PK {ITM, OWN, SHP#}

FK1 {ITM} REFERENCES item {ITM}

FK2 {OWN, SHP#} REFERENCES shop {OWN, SHP#}
```

```
-- On DTE (date-time), item ITM was sold in
-- quantity QTY, thru point of sale number POS#,
-- of shop number SHP#, of owner OWN.
--
sales {OWN, SHP#, POS#, DTE, ITM, QTY}
   PK {OWN, SHP#, POS#, DTE, ITM}

      FK1 {ITM, OWN, SHP#} REFERENCES
item_shop {ITM, OWN, SHP#}

          FK2 {OWN, SHP#, POS#} REFERENCES
point_of_sale {OWN, SHP#, POS#}
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
FK = Foreign Key
```

```
Using suffix # to save on screen space.
OK for SQL Server and Oracle, for others use _NO.
For example, rename SHP# to SHP_NO.
```

Comment: So as i understand the relation to SHP# and ITM# is 1:N right? so i just could create the item table with all it info like description and other data with columns for identify the shop and the owner as foreign keys right?

Comment: @IgorMytyuk : For each *item* and *shop*: that *item* may be available in more than one *shop*; each *shop* may carry more than one *item*.